# symfony2: How to remove related entity with doctrine / restrict annotation?

Tags: symfony, orm, annotations, doctrine, restrict

I have some bit of troubles with delete constraint in an entity.

I have an entity merchandise and an entity vehicle with a relation many to one in merchandise, so a merchandise only could be in one vehicle, and a vehicle could have many merchandise. So I have:

```
class Merchandise{
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vehicle",inversedBy="merchandise")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vehicle", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $vehicle;
}

class Vehicle{
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Merchandise",mappedBy="vehicle")
    */
    private $merchandise;
}
```

What I want to get is that when I try to delete a Merchandise which have a vehicle, the Merchandise couldn't be deleted.
But I don't know how can I put an ORM Level restrict constraint. I tried restrict={"remove"} but it doesn't exist in @ORM\OneToMany. 
I also try to put a preRemove function which return false, but it doesn't work :(

Any idea?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm not sure this really makes sense. If your merchandise can only belong to one vehicle then why would you be trying to delete it independently of a vehicle? It would make more sense for a manyToMany.

Answer (score 4):

ManyToOne / inversedBy is the OWNING side of the bidirectional relation from doctrine's point of view - which can lead to confusion.

To resolve your issue add cascade operation to your merchandise entity. example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vehicle",mappedBy="merchandise", cascade={"all"})
 */
```

cascade can be set to a combination of :

- persist
- remove
- merge
- detach
- *all*

Improve further by adding cascade ( ORM-level ) to your Vehicle entity aswell. example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Merchandise", mappedBy="vehicle", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 */
```

... or use onDelete ( database-level ) with one of

- SET NULL
- CASCADE

... like this

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Merchandise", inversedBy="vehicle", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
```

Now if you remove a Vehicle - the related Merchandise entities will be removed. Added Merchandises will automatically be saved.

... finally update your schema and drop -> re-create your database if constraints have not been updated and errors occur. Make sure both sides use the cascade option.

Read more in the documentation chapter [Transitive persistence / Cascade Operations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).

Comment: What I really want is that I couldn't remove a child if it has a parent...
So I have merchandising and vehicles individually, and when I add a merchandising to a vehicle, this merchandisin couldn't be removed.

Thanks!!

Comment: what's the translation on "restrict"? I want to restrict deleting an entity if it has any number of others related to it

Comment: "*restrict*" means disallow/forbid in this question's context. I think i didn't really understand the question here ... @Angel wanted to disallow the deletion of an entity that has a relation by himself... and i thought he wasn't able to delete the entity with a relation because of a foreign key issue :)